# Compiling and executing an nsi file from another nsi file using nsis code

Tags: nsis

Suppose I have two nsi files     `demo.nsi`    (compiles to `demo.exe`) and `setup.nsi`.  (compiles to `setup.exe`). I want to use `demo.nsi` inside setup.nsi in such a way that when `setup.exe` is executed, it compiles the `demo.nsi`, and then executes the `demo.exe`.
Just want to know if that is possible to do in nsis ?
Thanks.

Comment: Ey, 4 questions, still no answer accepted...

Comment: are you stalking me? ;)

Comment: Yes of course, who else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it could be possible like from e.g. any batch file:

- you need to call `ExecWait` to call `makensis.exe` for the compilation part
- and you can call the final executable with either `ExecWait` or `Exec` depending on you need to wait for the result or not.

Beware that if you want to do that in any host, and not only the one where you prepare your setup, you will have to embed the NSIS distribution in your setup to be able to call `makensis.exe` and all the included files that could be necessary (included files, plugins, and other resources).

Comment: Thanks mate for help. Although it doesn't seem such a cool idea to embed everything.

Comment: @user1986779: you need to compile nsis scripts in multiple hosts, or just where your nsis is installed?

Comment: its going to be on multiple hosts.

Comment: @smilepleeeaz: then the minimal stuff would be `makensis.exe` and at least one stub. After that it depends on what you want to compile. Embed quite everything if you need to compile any script, or embed just the functionalities that are used if you know by advance what the compiled script is using. Maybe several .nsh from contribs for UI and some includes, nothing from documentation or examples and perhaps no plugin. It could be little.